# How to return person with max sales in salesperson program- JAVA

Tags: java

Kind of confused by one part of my HW problem. It seems like it would be easy, but I can't put my finger on it. I am trying to return the salesperson with the max and min sales. I am confused on how to do that. Help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cray {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        final int SALESPEOPLE = 5;
        int[] sales = new int[SALESPEOPLE];
        int sum, maxperson, minperson;
        int max = sales[0];
        int min = sales[0];



        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Fill the 5 element array of sales with the user's input
        for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
            {
            System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson " + i + ": ");
            sales[i] = scan.nextInt();
            //Calculate the max and min sales
            //How do I return the salesperson i with the the max and min sales?
            if(sales[i] > max){
                max= sales[i];
            }
            if(sales[i] < min){
                min = sales [i];
            }


            }



        System.out.println("\nSalesperson   Sales");
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
            {
            System.out.println("     " + i + "         " + sales[i]);
            sum += sales[i];
            }

        System.out.println("\nTotal sales: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Average sales: " + sum/5);
        //WHere I want to print the max salesperson.
        System.out.println("Salesperson" +  );

          }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store the index count
declare and initialize two `int` variables before you start scanning the input:

```
   int maxindex=Integer.MIN_VALUE,minindex=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

And then assign your array index to them like this:

```
   if(sales[i] > max){
       max= sales[i];
       maxindex = i;
   }
   if(sales[i] < min){
       min = sales [i];
       minindex = i;
   }
```

Now you can directly get the salesperson with max and min sale

```
  System.out.println("Max sales person "+sales[maxindex]);
  System.out.println("Min sales person "+sales[minindex]);
```

I used a very simple trick here by storing the array indexes.
This is very basic approach though there may be more optimized approach for it.

Comment: I would use `max` instead of `sales[maxindex]`

Comment: I ended up initializing to 0 and just printing the max and min index as is. I think this was the best answer so I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in your for-loop, you're storing the maximum and minimum *sales*, not the *salespeople* who attained those sales. Therefore, you should be storing `i` in `max` / `min`, as opposed to `sales[i]`.

```
int max = 0, int min = 0

...

// in the for-loop
if(sales[i] > sales[max]){
    max = i;  // i.e. salesperson "i"
}
if(sales[i] < sales[min]){
    min = i;
}

...

System.out.println("Max salesperson: " +  max);
System.out.println("Min salesperson: " +  min);
```

Comment: @ARS let say sales[2]=10 and max=5 the as per your answer now max will be 2 instead of 10

Comment: @Abu Yes you're right - `max` should have been `sales[max]`. Thanks for pointing it out - see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your check for maximum

```
   if(sales[i] > max){
       max = sales[i];
       maxPerson = i;
   }
```

Comment: That's what I tried doing at first. But how would I print the maxperson value at the bottom? Maxperson is outside the scope.

Comment: Not if you put it outside the loop like max is.

Comment: I actually god it. I had to initialize max and minperson to 0. I just declared them origninally.

Answer (score 0):

Define two more variables as:

```
        int maxSalePersonIndex = 0;
        int minSalePersonIndex = 0;
```

Update your `if` as:

```
        if(sales[i] > max){
            max= sales[i];
            maxSalePersonIndex  = i;
        }
        if(sales[i] < min){
            min = sales [i];
            minSalePersonIndex = i;
        }
```

In the end, just print the values of `maxSalePersonIndex` and  `minSalePersonIndex`

```
    System.out.println("Salesperson index with max sale = " + maxSalePersonIndex);
    System.out.println("Salesperson index with min sale = " + minSalePersonIndex);
```